# UTF-8 characters don't display correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$result = '';
$str = 'Тугайный соловей';
for ($y=0; $y < strlen($str); $y++) {
    $tmp = mb_substr($str, $y, 1);
    $result = $result . $tmp;
}
echo 'result = ' . $result;
```

The output is:

```
Ð¢ÑƒÐ³Ð°Ð¹Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÑÐ¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²ÐµÐ¹
```

What can I do? I have to put `$result` into a MySQL database.

Answer (score 17):

What's the encoding of your file? It should be UTF8 too. What's the default charset of your http server? It should be UTF-8 as well.

Encoding only works if:

- the file is encoded correctly
- the server tells what's the encoding of the delivered file.

When working with databases, you also have to set the right encoding for your DB fields *and* the way the MySQL client communicates with the server (see `mysql_set_charset()`). Fields only are not enough because your MySQL client (in this case, PHP) could be set to ISO by default and reinterprets the data. So you end up with UTF8 DB -> ISO client -> injected into UTF8 PHP script. No wonder why it's messed up at the end :-)

How to serve the file with the right charset?

`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` is one solution

.htaccess file containing `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` is another one

HTML meta content-type might work too but it's always better to send this information using HTTP headers.

PS: you also have to use `mb_strlen()` because `strlen()` on UTF8 strings will probably report more than the real length.

Comment: There are 2 things to check, 1) Is your DB UTf-8, 2) Is your doc type UTF-8?

Comment: @Matthieu yeah, sad... I guess this is because most people work with english and don't worry about encoding ;-)

Comment: @Capsule: Huh? You still need the encoding with English!!

Comment: @tchrist of course but I was talking about encoding others than iso-8859-1, because unless you want to use specific punctuation or avoid using html entities, you could stick with iso-8859-1 when using english only. In fact you can stick with it when using french and some other languages too because common accents are part of the ISO charset. People tend to use UTF-8 because it's more universal and avoids (well, tries to avoid) headaches but most don't test if the whole setup is bullet proof because you won't detect any problem until you use UTF-8 specific characters.

Comment: @Capsule: French needs UTF-8, or at least, ISO 8859-15. Otherwise you miss œ, Œ, Ÿ.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, your code is in `windows-1251` encoding since it is Russian :) 
convert your string to utf-8:

```
$str = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to send a mix of data and don't want to specify utf-8 using a php header, you can add this html to your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 2):

If your database is UTF-8, it's ok for mysql.

For your echo, if you do it in a web site, put this in the top page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line at the beginning, after the connection with server:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    header("Content-type: application/octetstream");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    //print "$name_field\n$data";

    // با این کد درست شد
    print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding("$name_field\n$data", 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Why you sent your answer with Persian comment here? Not useful to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just using PHP echo with no HTML headers etc., this worked great for me.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
```