# "strange" characters

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$result = "";
$str = "Тугайный соловей";
for ($y=0; $y < strlen($str); $y++){
    $tmp = substr($str, $y, 1);
    $result = $result.$tmp;
}
echo "result = ".$result;
```

$result gives: Ð¢ÑƒÐ³Ð°Ð¹Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÑÐ¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²ÐµÐ¹

I'm looking for two weeks to solve this problem reading all kinds of articles but still .....

Thank you very much!

Comment: It has something to do with the codification (maybe utf-8)

Comment: what if you do just `echo $str;`? Does it give the same output?

Comment: These are not "strange", they're prefectly normal. It's just that a frightening number of programmers, including people implementing languages, opt not to care about multi-byte encodings, i.e. most of the world :(

Comment: most likely the encoding for the generated page is not set correctly (http header or `<meta>` tag). when you do not manipulate your string you don't need to use `mb_*` (multibyte) functions of php. in your example `echo "result =".$str;` oughta be enough though. assuming you want to perform operations on your characters (replace, upper/lowercase, etc.), please refer to the php documentation on [multibyte strings](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

Comment: Why are you [asking twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733336/utf-8-characters-dont-display-correctly) ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [multi-byte functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) not the plain string functions.

```
$result = "";
$str = "Тугайный соловей";
for ($y=0; $y < mb_strlen($str); $y++){
    $tmp = mb_substr($str, $y, 1);
    $result = $result.$tmp;
}
echo "result = ".$result;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your reactions !! I (now) do understand the multi_byte characters, but I can't solve the problem (until now). What is wrong with:

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and I see the right string in UTF-8 codification. If the page charset, or browser is set to ISO-8859-1 I get the wrong string. So using the right codification should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on Juanmi's answer re: charset types (and since I already took the screenshots)...

#### Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

[image: UTF-8]

#### Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

[image: ISO-8859--1]

Your code appears to work when the right encoding is specified, but it's treating each byte as its own character, which is not the correct way to handle UTF-8. You probably need the [multibyte-aware string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

Comment: Hidding the ENTER-key did sent my incomplete response. The question remanis: Why do I get that "strange" outut in this simple php-code? <?php
$inputString = "Тугайный соловей";
echo "inputString = ".$inputString."<br/>";
?>

Comment: What charset did your browser use during display?

Answer (score 0):

You are using functions that are not made for UTF-8 strings on a UTF-8 string

Use mb_substr instead

edit: the answer above by xeoncross is the same, use his code :)