# Display latin character in html

Tags: php, latin1

I have a PHP object displaying values as below when I use **var_dump($obj)**:

*object() (1) { ["name"]=> string(3) "**Lê**" ... }*

But when I **print $obj->name**, the browser displays "**LÃª**" instead.

My browser is displaying UTF-8.
HTML charset is also set to utf-8.

I tried with some functions but I didn't solve this.

could you please help me to solve this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have already had all checked items as below:

1. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
2. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
3. My browser is displaying UTF-8
4. The $obj is get from db table which set "character set" to utf-8 and "collation" to utf8_general_ci
5. PHP file is encoded to UTF-8

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733336/utf-8-characters-dont-display-correctly

Answer (score 2):

Set a UTF-8 `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

I've just tested this on PHP5.4.8, nginx, Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox. AFAIK, you'll get the same results in pretty much any PHP stack from at least the past 5 years.

```
<?php

$mystring = 'Lê';

print $mystring;
```

output:
LÃª

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$mystring = 'Lê';

print $mystring;
```

output:
Lê

Comment: I did it. HTML meta tag charset is utf-8. But it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Ducati You know this is not the same as a HTML meta tag, right? This is a header on the file itself.

Comment: Hi Blowski, thanks for your response. I used that code. 
I can print 'Lê' as well as it displays correct in html.
However my issue is that I can't display the property of object correctly.
I updated my question with new information. Please see it.

Comment: Oop, I found my issue. I used function htmlentities() in __get(). So when I print the object property, it is encoded to ISO-8859-1 (default of this function with PHP prior to 5.4.0). Thanks for taking your time to help me.