# Write String-Helper in Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, special-characters

My problem is that the german ü, ä, ö in HTML are displayed as not known sign .
You can write ü as "&uuml ;" ä as "&auml ;" and so one.
But is it not possible to replace ü with "&uuml ;" in a typescript method. The result will be "&uuml ;".

This is my method in typescript which replace ü with "&uuml ;"

```
public stringHelper(textUml: string): string {
    textUml = textUml.replace("ü", "&uuml;");
    debugger;
    return textUml;
}

<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addKeySkill()">{{stringHelper("Hinzufügen")}}</button>
```

Instead of displaying "Hinzufügen" its display "Hinzuf&uuml ;gen".

[image]

Comment: Why not going for `Custom Pipe`

Comment: As I see working fine for me--> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-25scqf-ah3cfj

Comment: strange, not on my computer

Comment: Your browser encoding must ve wrong. Umlaut are UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Writing it lke
`<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addKeySkill()">Hinzufügen</button>`
should work. 
If not check, if you saved your file in the correct encoding.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443288/in-a-html-file-with-charset-utf-8-do-i-still-need-to-replace-umlauts-with-auml

Comment: Otherwise SkyHighs Answer will display the correct text but I think you should check your encoding, so won't have to escape your umlauts at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex instead and apply `g` so all occurrences will be replaced (otherwise, only the first "ü" is replaced):

`textUml = textUml.replace('/ü/g', "&uuml;");`

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you use `{{ }}` in your HTML template, Angular escapes the string. This is thus expected behaviour that your `&` is escaped, and not considered as an HTML entity.

So you should leave it unescaped (with `ü`) and it should work fine.

If you still want to put the exact HTML code, and not escape the contents of a variable, you need to [define a custom pipe](https://medium.com/@AAlakkad/angular-2-display-html-without-sanitizing-filtering-17499024b079), and then use `innerHTML` to output the code.

In your example, once you define the pipe, you would put:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addKeySkill()">
  <span [innerHTML]="stringHelper('Hinzufügen') | keepHtml"></span>
</button>
```