# Text appears as "ŒÃ˜Â³Ã˜ÂªÃ›ÂŒ" on SQLite Database

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to read data from my SQLite database.

With this code in PHP, It works:

```
$db = new SQLite3('protected.sqlite');
if(isset($_GET['query'])) {
    $query = $_GET['query'];
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE protected="'.$query.'"');
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        echo utf8_encode($row["gender"]);
       // var_dump($row);
    }

} else {
   echo '{"status": "error","data": null,"message": "Failed to translate, Please try again"}';
}
```

But the gender is often in Arabic or Urdu, They appear as:

> Ã˜Â®Ã›Â†Ã˜Â´Ã›ÂŒ Ã˜Â¯Ã›Â•Ã™ÂˆÃ›ÂŽÃ˜Âª - Ã˜Â®Ã›Â†Ã˜Â´Ã›Â•Ã™ÂˆÃ›ÂŒÃ˜Â³Ã˜ÂªÃ›ÂŒ

How do i fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 characters don't display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733336/utf-8-characters-dont-display-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by removing `utf8_encode($row["gender"]);`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your code.

Comment: this is just a single php file no html